# Postgres: negating conditions in CASE statement

Tags: sql, postgresql, case

I have a list of rows I want to filter out from my result set based on some conditions. Currently, it looks like this in my query:

```
WHERE col1 = 'x' OR col1 ~~ '%y%' AND col2 = 'z' ...
```

Now I want to introduce a new column that documents the reason certain rows are filtered out:

```
SELECT ...
  , CASE WHEN condition1 THEN 'Exclusion Reason 1'
         WHEN condition2 THEN 'Exclusion Reason 2'
         ...
         ELSE ''
    END AS exclusion_reason
```

The problem: it doesn't seem to work the way I use negation:

```
SELECT ...
  , CASE WHEN condition1 THEN 'Reason 1'
         WHEN condition2 THEN 'Reason 2'
         WHEN NOT (col1 = 'x' OR col1 ~~ '%y%' AND col2 = 'z'...) THEN 'Reason 3'
         ELSE ''
    END AS exclusion_reason
```

It doesn't return any rows with `Reason 3`, although it should. Leaving out the NOT marks a subset of the rows:

```
SELECT ...
  , CASE WHEN condition1 THEN 'Reason 1'
         WHEN condition2 THEN 'Reason 2'
         WHEN (col1 = 'x' OR col1 ~~ '%y%' AND col2 = 'z'...) THEN 'Not Reason 3'
         ELSE ''
    END AS exclusion_reason
```

Why does the negation not work as expected and what is the correct syntax to use here?

Comment: Just for the comment that by [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-EXPRESS-EVAL) explicitly says: *"The order of evaluation of subexpressions is not defined. In particular, the inputs of an operator or function are not necessarily evaluated left-to-right or in any other fixed order."*, then it is safer to surround with `()` exact parts need no match. In given example `( (col1 = 'x' OR col1 ~~ '%y%') AND col2 ...)` etc.

Answer (score 2):

I am going to guess that the reason is `NULL` values, so something like this:

```
    WHEN NOT (col1 = 'x' OR col1 ~~ '%y%' AND col2 = 'z'...) OR col1 IS NULL THEN 'Reason 3'
```

A `NULL` value in a condition will return `NULL`.  `NOT NULL` is still `NULL` -- and that is treated as false.